# получить html из выбранного блока через класс

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет! Я только начал разбираться в JS и Jquery, но так и не нашел решения.
Есть html разметка

```
<div class="link">Привет</div>
<div class="link">Hello</div>

<div id="container">Контент</div>
```

При клике на блок с классом "link" в блоке с классом "container" фраза контент заменялась на "Привет" или "Hello" соответственно.

Использовать id вместо классов к сожалению не вариант(

Comment: исходя из написанного, едва можно догадаться, что конкретно вы спрашиваете

Comment: При клике на "привет" вместо "контент" должно быть "привет".
При клике на "Hello" вместо "контент" должно быть "Hello".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".link").on("click", function() {
  var text = $(this).html();
  $("#container").html(text);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link">Привет</div>
<div class="link">Hello</div>

<div id="container">Контент</div>
```